# Firing method then I in view half of dataSource array

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview, infinite-scroll

How can I make than some method fires then I scroll to half of dataSource array in tableView?

I want to make infinite scroll like this

Comment: Please make a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableviewDelegate` method `willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:` and check `indexPath.row` with `dataSource` array then fire the method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if ([dataSourceArray count]/2 == indexPath.row) {
         //invoke the method here
     }
}
```